# Certification of a jar(not containing applet )

Tags: java, digital-certificate, client-certificates

I am new to certification in java.Just on another post just now,I found out that it is not possible to use jarsigner on java apps,its only used for applets.Could anyone confirm this?

Next I would like to know,what is the common way people developers give thier apps to the clients,I mean do they not put any certificate for it?I mean a year or six months certificate.

**This I am talking is with respect to a normal java app not an applet**

**UPDATE**
This is what I tried:I jarsigned my app yesterday and gave the validity of 1 day,today when I saw it never got expired.So thats why I was wondering if it is only for applets?

Comment: Any jar can be signed. Only a few special cases must be. An application can do signature checks of its own.

Comment: how to do it?please provide some help

Comment: You may want to read the Java Tutorials [Signing Code and Granting It Permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/index.html) lesson. It is part of the [Security Features in Java SE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/TOC.html) trail which you may want to study completely.

Comment: I have done that already,but it never expired

Comment: In that case you may want to update your question to reflect what you have tried yet, what you observed, and how that deviates from your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a trusted way of delivering your jars to your client, you do not need to sign it. A "normal" Java program also does not do anything different for a signed jar.

However there is a difference if you use some other way of distributing your application. You already mentioned applets. The user cannot really be sure who is offering the application. By signing it, you can ensure it is comming from the trusted guy (you).

Another big usecase for this is Java Webstart. If you want to distribute your application with that tool (a good idea), you need to sign the Jar files if your application wants to have some extra permissions (like accessing files, network IO, stuff like that). If the user then trusts those certificates, the application is started.

As for the duration: Usually those applications are signed with rather long validity (> 2 years), usually longer than the applications supposed lifetime.

Comment: Whatever research I have done,I coudnt find anything to license a java app without expiiry

Comment: Well, it is not meant for licensing. Signing a jar is for making sure the user can trust the code has not been tampered with. For licensing, you can easily implement your own mechanism.

Comment: what about the validity flag in the jarsigner?

Comment: You mean during `jarsigner -verify`? This is just a warning that the certificate is not valid anymore. Most tools (like Java Webstart) will then issue a warning to the user that the certificate is expired. But if the signing process is valid, security is not compromised. The Java VM will ignore all this information no matter what, since the "signature" stuff is only in the Manifest and will not normally be evaluated during class loading. You however could make your application check the Manifest of your jar file and verify that the certificate is still valid or exit your program if not.

Comment: sorry in keystore I meant

Comment: How to check the manifest file as you suggested?could you provide me some code..I am new to this

Comment: This is not so easy actually. I would recommend you have a look on how Java Webstart is doing the verification (look up the source code and the specification). Of course you have to verify that the jar was signed with your certificate and that your certificate is still valid. You should however find all the code in the Java Webstart implementation.